# How to set bandwidth limit per domain on Google Kubernetes Engine

Tags: google-cloud-platform, kubernetes-ingress, google-kubernetes-engine

We are a website builder SaaS platform, where users are building their FREE websites and are connecting their domains.

We would like to set a limit per domain, example 100mb/month, so when that bandwidth limit is hit we can restrict access to that domain with a message like "You have reached your limit".

This limit can be set for example via custom headers in the request for the specific domain or maybe on a Load Balancer's level.

We weren't able to find documentation on that topic, so decided to ask here!

Please help!

Regards,
Gev

Comment: The reason that you cannot find anything is that Google does not have a method to limit bandwidth to a specified amount. You will have to implement that policy yourself. Once the user hits a certain bandwidth limit you switch their site to the notice page that you mentioned. Keep in mind today that real web pages have graphics, large css and js files, etc. 100 Mbit per month is like one to ten web page views per day. Not a realistic service to offer.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to use [Pulse Virtual Traffic Manager](https://www.pulsesecure.net/vtm/overview/) for control the network traffic through your domains. It's in [Google Marketplace](https://cloud.google.com/marketplace/) for deploy directly in your infrastructure.

Also, you can think to use the HTTPs [load balancing features](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/load-balancing-overview) in combination with [Cloud DNS](https://cloud.google.com/dns/docs/overview#dns-forwarding) forwarding and [Cloud CDN](https://cloud.google.com/cdn/docs/caching#cdn-requests) (caching) for optimize the network traffic and redirections to the different domains.